# How to import folders with Lua

Tags: file, import, lua, directory, load

I have a problem with one of my scripts, I'm trying to load a file when the script is running, but I have an error message which says he doesn't find any file with the name I gave.

Here is when I put the condition to load the file :

```
function checkAll()
    if (global:getCountFight() >= (LAST_NB_FIGHT+MAX_FIGHT)) then
        LAST_NB_FIGHT = global:getCountfight() 
        printMsg("Déconnecte le personnage pendant "..SLEEP_TIME.." heure(s)")
        global:reconnect(SLEEP_TIME)
    elseif (character:level()<8) then
        goHomeAndLoadTrajet("[Combat] Bouftous")
        setMinMonsters(1)
        setMaxMonsters(8)
        setForceMonsters({}) 
        SLEEP_LVL = 50
        SLEEP_TIME = 6
```

Here is what the fonction goHomeAndLoadTrajet calls :

```
function goHomeAndLoadTrajet(trajetName)
    trajetName = checkTrajetName(trajetName)
    if trajetName ~= u_NEXT_TRAJET and trajetName ~= LAST_TRAJET then
        u_NEXT_TRAJET = trajetName
        goHome()
    end
end
```

Which calls :

```
function checkTrajetName(trajetName)
    if (file_exists(INCLUDES_PATH..trajetName)) then
        return trajetName
    elseif (file_exists(INCLUDES_PATH..trajetName..".lua")) then
        return trajetName..".lua"
    else
        printMsg("Le trajet '"..trajetName.."' n'existe pas !", "ERREUR")
        return
    end
```

And which finally calls :

```
function file_exists(name)
   local f=io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
end
```

So now I'm confused.. Thanks :)

EDIT : The INCLUDES_PATH is a variable which contains my path,
`INCLUDES_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SnowbotTouch\\Scripts Lua\\Trajets\\includes\\"`

Comment: Does the error message come from `checkTrajetName()`?

Comment: Yes ! @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: What happens when you directly invoke `checkTrajetName(trajetName)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to guess as to what may be wrong; you just need to output the error message from the `io.open` call:

```
function file_exists(name)
   local f, err =io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then
     io.close(f)
   else
     print(err)
   end
   return f~=nil
end
```

The error message will include the file name, so it should tell you unambiguously if there is a problem with the file name, permissions, or something else.

Comment: Thanks ! It was a problem with the permissions !! Thanks a lot